# Java Hibernate Exception not exposing the Raise Error Exception

Tags: hibernate, exception, raise

Software Versions Used:

Java Version : openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)

Hibernate Version : 5.3.16 Final

Scenario:  The Update Trigger associated to “PatientVisitProcs” Table called “PatientVisitProcs_Update”
Has implementation for throwing RaiseError whenever we Update some fields of the table under Closed Batch condition.

Trigger Code Snippet:
RAISERROR(50972,11,2)
ROLLBACK TRAN

We get the following result from Database as in the snapshot below:
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspRaiseError, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 12]
Error 50972, severity 11, state 2 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages.
If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Problem:
Whereas in Java Hibernate Exception.
We get the Bottom Error Only :Line starting with Msg 3609..,
We are in Search of the Top Error : Line Starting Error 50972…
Standalone JPA Implementation gets this message though as detailedMessage.
See the snap attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jirxg.png):

Comment: Can some one suggest what is the fix?

Comment: You did not formulate a question or explained what you want vs. what is happening, so not sure if anyone can help you at this point.

Comment: My Question is simple: Error 50972, severity 11, state 2 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. How to get this line returned from DB as Error caught in Java Exception??

Comment: I do not understand what of this text is the _error_ of the application, and what is text written by *you*. Maybe you should try to format the question a bit better. Anyway, if the exception does not offer you accessors for the information you need, parse the toString representation to extract what you need.